# How to fix Run-Time error '91' in custom command bar VBA

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have an excel workbook with multiple sheets and am trying to limit user ability to insert/delete rows within the first worksheet. I currently have VBA code in place that removes (hides) the 'Insert' and 'Delete' buttons in the Row menu, and inserts to new fake insert/delete buttons which both create pop-up boxes instructing the user in how to properly remove/add rows (I have some key-bound macros which simultaneously delete/add rows across multiple select sheets).

This code works SOMETIMES, but most often returns a "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set".

From picking through a multitude of similar questions, I've determined that I'm most likely not initializing the command bar object correctly (or something along those lines), but I haven't been able to figure out how to correctly do it. Can anyone assist in correcting the error?

Here is the code within the sheet object:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

'reset to standard context menu before adding new option
Application.CommandBars("Row").Reset

'removes standard Delete and Insert menu bar items
Application.CommandBars("Row").FindControl(ID:=293).Visible = False
Application.CommandBars("Row").FindControl(ID:=296).Visible = False
        
'add custom row deletion call
With Application.CommandBars("Row").Controls.Add
    .Caption = "Delete Row"
    .Style = msoButtonCaption
    .OnAction = "DeleteRow"
End With
With Application.CommandBars("Row").Controls.Add
    .Caption = "Insert Row"
    .Style = msoButtonCaption
    .OnAction = "InsertRow"
End With

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
'get rid of the customization when you're done with this sheet
Application.CommandBars("Row").Reset

End Sub
```

Here is the code within the workbook object:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Source As Range)
'resets menu bars when workbook sheets are changed
Application.CommandBars("Row").Reset
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    'Resets menu bars when workbook is deactivated
    Application.CommandBars("Row").Reset
End Sub
```

Here is are the modules for the added buttons -

Module 1:

```
Public Sub DeleteRow()

    MsgBox "Manually deleting rows from this Estimate will disconnect linked sheets. Please use CTRL-Q to delete rows.", vbOKOnly, "WARNING: Delete Rows"

End Sub
```

Module 2:

```
Public Sub InsertRow()

    MsgBox "Manually inserting rows into this Estimate will disconnect linked sheets. Please use CTRL-A to add rows.", vbOKOnly, "WARNING: Insert Row"

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is highlighted when it errors?

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams - The line that highlights with the error is the following: >Application.CommandBars("Row").FindControl(ID:=296).Visible = False

Comment: Oddly if I switch the lines so ID:=296 is first it works. It seems to change 296 to 3181 or 3183 when either of them is hidden.

Comment: @Warcupine - Switching the order is working perfectly for me! That is odd, I wouldn't have guessed that switching them around would make a difference. I wonder why the ID for 'Delete' stays static if the other ID changes dynamically like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting these controls visibility to false appears to be modifying the collection, removing the ID you're looking for.

Code to see IDs:

```
Sub test()
    Dim ctl As Object
    
    For Each ctl In Application.CommandBars("Row").Controls
        Debug.Print ctl.ID, ctl.Caption, ctl.TooltipText
    Next
    Debug.Print vbNewLine, vbNewLine
End Sub
```

If I run this before modifying:

| ID | Caption | Tooltip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | Cu&t | Cu&t |
| 19 | &Copy | &Copy |
| 22 | &Paste | &Paste |
| 21437 | Paste &Special... | Paste &Special... |
| 3624 | &Paste Table | &Paste Table |
| 32713 | Data T&ype |  |
| 296 | &Rows | Insert Rows |
| 293 | &Delete | &Delete |
| 3125 | Clear Co&ntents | Clear Co&ntents |
| 855 | &Format Cells... | &Format Cells... |
| 541 | &Row Height... | &Row Height... |
| 883 | &Hide | &Hide (Ctrl+9) |
| 884 | &Unhide | &Unhide (Ctrl+Shift+( ) |
| 3626 | &Remove Hyperlinks | &Remove Hyperlinks |

Running it as you have it with ID:=293 first:

| ID | Caption | Tooltip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | Cu&t | Cu&t |
| 19 | &Copy | &Copy |
| 22 | &Paste | &Paste |
| 21437 | Paste &Special... | Paste &Special... |
| 3624 | &Paste Table | &Paste Table |
| 32713 | Data T&ype |  |
| 3183 | &Insert | Insert Cells |
| 293 | &Delete | &Delete |
| 3125 | Clear Co&ntents | Clear Co&ntents |
| 855 | &Format Cells... | &Format Cells... |
| 541 | &Row Height... | &Row Height... |
| 883 | &Hide | &Hide (Ctrl+9) |
| 884 | &Unhide | &Unhide (Ctrl+Shift+( ) |
| 3626 | &Remove Hyperlinks | &Remove Hyperlinks |

You can see that ID 296 is gone from the list and 3183 is now present. Testing manually it does the same thing, adds a row.

After swapping the lines and successfully running your script:

| ID | Caption | Tooltip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | Cu&t | Cu&t |
| 19 | &Copy | &Copy |
| 22 | &Paste | &Paste |
| 21437 | Paste &Special... | Paste &Special... |
| 3624 | &Paste Table | &Paste Table |
| 32713 | Data T&ype |  |
| 3183 | &Insert | Insert Cells |
| 293 | &Delete | &Delete |
| 3125 | Clear Co&ntents | Clear Co&ntents |
| 855 | &Format Cells... | &Format Cells... |
| 541 | &Row Height... | &Row Height... |
| 883 | &Hide | &Hide (Ctrl+9) |
| 884 | &Unhide | &Unhide (Ctrl+Shift+( ) |
| 3626 | &Remove Hyperlinks | &Remove Hyperlinks |
| 1 | Delete Row | Delete Row |
| 1 | Insert Row | Insert Row |

No matter what 296 seems to be replaced while 293 sticks around. I can't reproduce it now but while testing I saw ID 3181 instead of 3183 so I wouldn't rely on that value.

I have no clue why it would do this.